# Scaling of Close Votes?

Tags: discussion

Recently I noticed that flags are scaled with reputation (you can get up to 100 flags, you start at 10)  and the delete votes (Just read about it can't cast them now) are scaled to (you start at 10 and can get up to 35).

As you shall cast close votes instead of flaging posts once you reached the reputation, I guess the chance is much higher to run out of close votes than out of flags. Is there a special reason, why there is no scaling for close votes?

Comment: In all my days, only once (or twice?) I managed to run out of closing votes. And I had to work very hard for doing that. On the other hand, with nearly 80 daily flags I don't think I'll ever run out of flags...

Comment: I think flags are scaled by having other flags marked helpful. Is that not the case?

Comment: @mixedmath flags are scaled with helpful flags and with reputation, for every 2 k reputation you get a new flag, I don't know how many helpful flags you need for that

Comment: @mixedmath: You get an extra flag per 10 helpful flags; I'm not sure about whether or not there is a decrease when flags are rejected. That's how it was when flag weight was the "public player" of flagging, rather than "helpful flags" today.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I nearly run out of close vote once, but I think the maximum flags i used are 5 on a day I guess, maybe i didn't make it to clear, but I am more interested in why they aren't scale than in to scale them

Comment: My guess is because there is a measure of how "correct" the flag was; and it seems impossible to measure how "correct" a vote to close is.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But the delete votes are scaled to, how to measure them ?

Comment: I never knew there was a count for delete votes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila As I unterstood the privelege description there is one.

Comment: Hm. So I see. I suppose I never reached the end of that line...